# Gutenberg is there a way to know if the current block is reusable?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

So I have developed some blocks using React, I save my css generated in the post meta, that's works fine.  In the case of reusable blocks:

- Whene we set a block as reusable this block will saved as hidden CPT (wp_block) as the documentation. (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/key-concepts/#reusable-blocks).
- Since the block is reusable I wanted to save the css generated for the reusable block in one place (post meta for wp_block CPT for example), that's will achieve the goal of reusable block, whene the reusable block changed, this will affect all place (posts/pages) that use this reusable block.
  For that I wanted to check if rendred block is reusable to handle some logic?

Comment: What do you mean by "the current block" - do you mean PHP-side, when the reusable block is being rendered?

Comment: No, "current block" in the post editor, check it using React